# Not able to update google contacts data for a particular contact

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

```
foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact){
                    $return[] = array(
                    'id'=>$contact['id']['$t'],
                    'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
                    'phone' => isset($contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']) ? $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'] :false,
                    );
                }

                    $count = -1;
                    $contactId;
                    foreach($return as $value) {
                    $count++;

                    if ((strcmp($value['name'], $checkname) == 0) && (strcmp($value['phone'], $oldphone) == 0)) {
                        $contactid=$value['id'];
                       }      
                   }  
/* The code with problem starts here:*/    
                   $service = new Google_Service_Mirror($client);
                   $updatedContact = $service->contacts->get($contactId);
                   $updatedContact->setDisplayName($putname);
                   $updatedContact->setPhoneNumber($newphone);
                   return $service->contacts->update($contactId, $updatedContact);
/*The code with problem ends here:*/
```

I am not able to update the contacts in the google contacts. It seems that there is some authorization missing.

http://119.81.145.44

Error calling GET
https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/contacts/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2Fcontacts%2Fshisindood%2540gmail.com%2Fbase%2F1762fb1e0dca10ef
(403) Insufficient Permission

Please tell me what do I need to do to solve the problem. The code above is just an extract. Please ask me for more code if needed. Thank you.

Comment: I used this link : https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/update

Comment: [DaImTo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) - can u help me with this - thank you

Comment: Try to remove quotes near `$t` variable.